# Appcombat based ActionBar theme not working on newer devices

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I've created a ActionBar Style Using the tool ActionBar Style Generator ( http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator );I selected appcombat at the style compatibility selection list, because I need my app to be compatible with Android 2.3 devices; but when I downloaded and implemented the theme,the styles are only shown on my Android 2.3 emulated device; in newer devices it only shows the deafault ones. This is the code:

**/values/styles.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Iedecap" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_iedecap</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Iedecap</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Iedecap</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Iedecap</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Iedecap</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Iedecap</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_iedecap</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_iedecap</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Iedecap</item>

                <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Iedecap.Widget</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_iedecap</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_iedecap</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_iedecap</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Iedecap</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_iedecap</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Iedecap</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_iedecap</item>   
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_iedecap</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_iedecap</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_iedecap</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_iedecap</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_iedecap</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_iedecap</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Iedecap" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_iedecap</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Iedecap.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Iedecap</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Iedecap</item>
    </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hipano.idecapmovil" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Iedecap" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I think this is pretty strange since my entire code was generated by an automatic tool.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of your emulators or devices? If you are using android studio, make sure you have `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"` include in your gradle file. If you are using eclipse, make sure you add the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` jar file

Answer (score 3):

Per the note at the top of the Action Bar Style Generator you used, it has been deprecated and does not work with AppCompat v21.

Per the [Using the Material Theme training](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar), the Material theme (and AppCompat theme's which backport / use Material theming) theming is primarily done by `colorPrimary` and other similar attributes.

You'll find more details on how to theme using AppCompat / Material in the [AppCompat v21 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).